# Catch if user presses enter key in textbox

Tags: vb.net, events, keydown

I'm trying to catch in a `Event` if the user presses the enter key. If followed these instructions found on the [MSDN documentation pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752054(v=vs.110).aspx).

This is my `Event` code for the `Textbox`:

```
Private Sub tbOccurrenceElevation_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles tbOccurrenceElevation.KeyDown

    ' Check if the enter key is pressed
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Then
        OccurrenceElevation_Changed()
    End If

End Sub
```

---

My problem is: when I push any button on the keyboard the `Event` is triggered, but when I press the enter ( return ) key nothing happens?

I tried changing the `Textbox` property to `AcceptsReturn = True` but no luck.

Extra info: The textbox is located on a UserControl and not a form control.

Comment: I've made a quick test. If the textbox is in a user control and in the form containing that control `AcceptButton` is setted, it does not fire the event when enter is pressed

Comment: Euhmm the user control is added into a dock-able window object from Autodesk Inventor. So this will be causing the problem then I guess?

Comment: It's possible. I guess the parent window is catching the enter press event, so it does not go down to your control.

Comment: Try using RichTextBox I faced similar problem, I used RichTextBox instead of simple textbox. Simple textbox is no catching keyboard events in UserControl but RichTextBox does.

Answer (score 1):

If something else is stopping the text box from receiving the enter key you could try overriding [**`ProcessCmdKey`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `UserControl` instead.

It might work, but it all depends on where in the event chain that the parent intercepts the message.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Return AndAlso tbOccurrenceElevation.Focused = True Then
        'Do your stuff here.
        Return True 'We've handled the key press.
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Comment: This function does not trigger with any key being pressed. :sadface: I also asked at Autodesk for a reply but no response (yet..). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Mech_Engineer : That's too bad. I hope someone can help you over there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub tbOccurrenceElevation_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles tbOccurrenceElevation.KeyDown

    ' Check if the enter key is pressed
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter or e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Then
        OccurrenceElevation_Changed()
    End If

End Sub
```

You have to remember most of the keyboards have both Enter and Return. The code for those is different so you have to include them both